# Dynamic array of pointer to structs - do I really need to explicitly allocate space for ea element?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    char letter;
}* Foo;
```

And an array like this:

```
Foo* items = malloc(sizeof(Foo) * 4);
```

From my understanding and from the (accepted) answer to this question [Dynamic array of pointers to structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434250/dynamic-array-of-pointers-to-structs), I would expect the above line to only reserve the memory for 4 Foo items, but doesn't initialize it - i.e., if I try to access `items[i]->num`, I should get some kind of error.
Also, in order to insert item into this array, I should do this:

```
items[0] = malloc(sizeof(*items[0]));
```

However, I did a little test, and seems like the following code prints `1` and `a` just fine:

```
Foo* items = malloc(sizeof(Foo) * 2);
items[0]->num = 4;
items[0]->letter = 'a';
printf("items[0] = {num=%d, char=%c}\n", items[0]->num, items[0]->letter);
```

I'm confused. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointers. I was lost with the second `malloc()` because it seems that there is only one level of indirection there. Do not `typedef` poitners. What is this `items[0]->char`? Are you sure? This code should not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial malloc:

```
Foo* items = malloc(sizeof(Foo) * 4);
```

Is creating an array of 4 pointers, since `Foo` is a pointer type.  So your second malloc:

```
items[0] = malloc(sizeof(*items[0]));
```

Makes sense, since you're allocating a struct to that pointer.

However, the assignment you're doing leads to undefined behavior because you didn't do the second `malloc` and therefore no space has been allocated to `items[0]` yet.  C won't prevent you from writing to a memory location you shouldn't be writing to.  And once you do that, anything can happen.

One thing that's a bit confusing here is that you used `typedef` to define a pointer type.  That can lead to a lot of confusion since it's not apparent by looking at the type that it's a pointer.  And in this case, because of how you defined `Foo`, you had an extra layer of pointer indirection you probably don't need.

So if you define your struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    char letter;
} Foo;
```

Then this can be done safely:

```
Foo* items = malloc(sizeof(Foo) * 2);
items[0].num = 4;
items[0].letter = 'a';
printf("items[0] = {num=%d, char=%c}\n", items[0].num, items[0].letter);
```

Now the malloc creates an array of structs instead of an array of pointers to structs, so an additional layer of mallocs is no longer necessary.

Comment: Well. Let's just say I have to work with what I have - i.e., using these structs as is. I didn't define them.
And yes, I agree, if they're just struct, it would be much simpler.

Comment: @abcXYZ In that case, you need to perform an additional `malloc` for each element in the array.

Comment: Alright. So the second malloc is definitely needed, which leads me to another question, supposed I'm given an instance of Foo that was created somewhere else. I can safely do `items[0] = givenFoo` without the second `malloc`, correct?

Comment: @abcXYZ If it was created elsewhere, that means some other routine already malloced the space for it, so no you would not have to in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate structs and save its pointer to `items`'s elements if you want to use structs. Otherwise, the `item`'s elements are junk and access to it may cause errors.

The second test may worked fine due to the optimization which removes `malloc` and pass the values of `items[0]->num` and `items[0]->letter` directly to `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have reserved enough space for the `Foo` array  and probably one element but it's not the expected behavior, there is no expected behavior in this case because what you do invokes undefined behavior.

This will fail if you add more fields to the struct, because then `2 * sizeof(void *)` will not be enough. To test it, try adding 2 pointers to the struct like this<sup>1</sup>

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    char letter;
    void *pointers[2];
} *Foo;
```

If you want you can do it right, and this is another reason **not to `typedef` a pointer**, this would work

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    char letter;
    void *pointers[2];
} Foo;

Foo *foo_pointer = malloc(N * sizeof(Foo));
/*                                 ^ this would be wrong if `Foo' were a pointer */
if (foo_pointer == NULL)
    please_abort_this_do_not_continue_because_malloc_has_failed();
foo_pointer[0].num = 1;
foo_pointer[0].letter = 'a';
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It really annoys me to write this, because `typedef`ing a pointer is never a good idea</sub>

Comment: Alright. So if this is undefined behavior then my question is, what is a good/best practice in this case suppose I can't change the struct?
How do I create and insert elements into such an array? Is the second malloc for each individual element needed?