# Void pointer to struct pointer inside a structure without dereferencing it

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void-pointers

Let's imagine I have 3 different types of datasets in 3 different structs:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    //...
}DATATYPE1;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    //...
}DATATYPE2;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    //...
}DATATYPE3;
```

Then imagine I want one of those types of data to be assigned to a main struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int b;
    void* data;
    //...
}OBJECT;
```

Say I declare `OBJECT* abc = malloc(sizeof(OBJECT));` and `DATATYPE1* dt1 = malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE1));`
Is there a way I could then cast in the code something like this:

```
abc->data = dt1;
```

and then call:

```
(abc->data)->a;
```

without dereferencing the `abc->data` pointer back to `e.g. DATATYPE1* dp = abc->data` and then use `dp->a;`

Comment: 1) Dont use all-uppercase names for anything else than macros or enum-constants. 2) Never use `void *` without true need. Write type-safe code! 3) How is the compiler supposed to know which type your `void *` points to without a cast? 4) What is your **actual** problem you try to solve?

Comment: That's the point it is not I know. But is there any way it could possibly work like near that?

Comment: Could? Maybe (if you could make clear about point 4). The actual question is: **should you**? Which is easier to answer: **NO!**

Comment: The point I wanted to try and see if possible is if I could use the structs fields via the void pointer without using `DATATYPE1* dt1 = malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE1));`

Comment: Please read a C book! This is not related to dynamic memory allocation. Without offence, but you either have some fundamental missunderstanding or you have a problem to explain the problem properly. Both are essential prerequisites to write a proper program.

Comment: You can use a cast to avoid introducing a temporary pointer variable of the desired type, e.g. by accessing `((DATATYPE1*)abc->data)->a`. But it makes the code look uglier. I think you are better off using the temporary pointer variables for clarity.

Comment: Is it supposed to be significant that your three data types all have an initial member of the same type, and that's the one you are accessing?  C *does* have some provisions that would be relevant there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the problem is that you want to access the `a` field of your three `DATATYPE`S, without knowing which `DATATYPE` is actually present. The answer, is yes you can, because the C specification explicitly says that whatever `DATATYPE` is present, the pointer points at the first member of the structure, and hence can be safely cast to that type.

See: [Are there any guarantees about C struct order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057174/are-there-any-guarantees-about-c-struct-order) and especially:

> 15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units
>   in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order
>   in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.

Hence, the following code allows you to access a:

```
OBJECT* abc = malloc(sizeof(OBJECT));
abc->data = malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE1));
int* pointerToA = (int*) abc->data;
```

Whether this is good programming practice is another question, that I will not answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare everything that you will make reference in your C code. This is the only way to the compiler knows the size and location of the object in that specific address.

I think you can use anonymous union blocks and do something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int b;
    union {
       void* data;
       DATATYPE1 *dt1;
       DATATYPE2 *dt2:
       DATATYPE3 *dt3;
    };    
} OBJECT;
```

then use :

```
OBJECT* abc = (OBJECT*)malloc(sizeof(OBJECT));
DATATYPE1* dt1 = (DATATYPE1*)malloc(sizeof(DATATYPE1));
abc->data = (void *)dt1;
int val = abc->dt1->a;
```

Comment: There's no need for any of those casts, but everything here seems correct.  It's hard to determine whether this actually answers the question, though, as the OP seems a bit uncertain just what he wants to know.  Nevertheless, a union may indeed be a good way for the OP to approach his problem.

Comment: I agree with you. I tried to show him what I think that can produce the code that closely resembles with his desire. Thanks for commenting on the casts, they really are not necessary.